# Dynamic WireMock server in groovy test - Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, junit5, spock, wiremock

Regarding the article: https://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/

I tried doing my own server:

```
    @RegisterExtension
    static WireMockExtension wm1 = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
            .options(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort())
            .build();
```

But i changed unknown method `wireMockConfig()` to `new WireMockConfiguration()`

In `groovy` test i get that an error `Method threw 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException' exception.` Property is `getWm1`.

Is this issue with `spock` and `wiremock` integration ?

Wiremock 2.33.0

Spock-core-2.2-groovy-3.0

springBootVersion=2.7.4

springCloudVersion=2021.0.3

Maybe this code does not work in integration test ?

EDIT:
I was missing `import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig;`
IntelliJ did not find this import automatically.
But this code does exactly the same - `new WireMockConfiguration()`.

Comment: There are a few known problems with Spock erroneously generating setter calls where actually it should just access fields. Some have been fixed, so maybe you should try with Spock 2.3 and see if the upgrade solves your problem.

Comment: Please, next time provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a complete, minimal example, not just a snippet without even a surrounding class and imports. I had to make up my own in order to answer your question, which was somewhat annoying, because in situations like this I always feel that I am doing someone else's job, rather than just helping him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment, I also just saw your `@RegisterExtension`. Please note that the Spock 2.x test engine is a separate test engine on the JUnit 5 platform, it does **not** run on top of the Jupiter engine. Spock is a sibling rather than a child to Jupiter. Therefore, you cannot simply use Jupiter-specific annotations or extensions. You should rather do something like this, because [WireMock does not provide its own Spock 2.x extension](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1697):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74613761

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options

class WireMockTest extends Specification {
  @Shared
  WireMockServer wiremockServer

  def setupSpec() {
    wiremockServer = new WireMockServer(options().dynamicHttpsPort())
    wiremockServer.start()
  }

  def cleanupSpec() {
    wiremockServer.stop()
  }

  def cleanup() {
    wiremockServer.resetAll()
  }

  def test() {
    stubFor(get("/api-1-thing").willReturn(ok()))
    stubFor(get("/api-2-stuff").willReturn(ok()))

    expect:
    wiremockServer.httpsPort()
  }
}
```

There is, however, a third-party Spock extension which enables you to use Jupiter annotations and also Jupiter extensions. I do not have any experience with it, but it seems to work for WireMock:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q74613761

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit5.WireMockExtension
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension
import spock.lang.Specification

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.ok
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig

/**
 * Needs <ul>
 *   <li><tt>com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8</tt>,</li>
 *   <li><tt>org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api</tt> in version fitting with Spock and WireMock,</li>
 *   <li><a href="https://github.com/xvik/spock-junit5"><tt>ru.vyarus:spock-junit5</tt></a> for being able to use Jupiter extensions in Spock 2.x.</li>
 * <ul>
 */
class WireMockJupiterExtensionTest extends Specification {
  @RegisterExtension
  static WireMockExtension wm1 = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
    .options(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort())
    .build()
  @RegisterExtension
  static WireMockExtension wm2 = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
    .options(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)))
    .build()

  def test() {
    wm1.stubFor(get("/api-1-thing").willReturn(ok()))
    wm2.stubFor(get("/api-2-stuff").willReturn(ok()))

    expect:
    wm1.runtimeInfo.httpsPort
    wm1.port
  }
}
```

I would recommend not to rely on Jupiter-specific stuff, pulling it into Spock, as long as there are good alternatives like in this case, simply setting up WireMock by yourself. You can also put the configuration into a base spec and extend that base spec for your WireMock specs.